# Python multiprocessing. How do you get the status of the parent from the child?

Tags: python, linux, pid, python-multiprocessing

I'm writing an application (Linux) using the multiprocessing module, which spawns several children.  When a child dies, I can detect it from the parent using something like the following:

```
process = multiprocessing.Process(...)
if process.is_alive():
  print "Process died"
```

However, I'd also like to be able to detect from the children if the parent is still alive, to handle cleanup if someone goes and kill -9's the parent process.

From my example above, I can get the parent id with either:

```
process._parent_pid
```

Or:

```
os.getppid()
```

But I can't find an easy way to get a status of the process.  I'd rather not write something to grep/regex the ps list using subprocess.  Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could compare the parent's process id against `1`; if it is `1` then you can deduce the parent process has terminated, because the subprocess now has the `init` process (pid 1) as parent.

```
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def subprocess():
    while True:
        ppid = os.getppid()
        print "Parent process id:", ppid
        if ppid == 1:
            print "Parent process has terminated"
            break
        time.sleep(1)

p = Process(target=subprocess)
p.start()
```

Comment: Seems like this approach won't work in a docker container, because the root process (parent in this case) has always PID 1. On the other hand if the process with PID 1 dies in docker, the container will exit.

Comment: this won't work on windows. "If the parent process has already exited, Windows machines will still return its id; others systems will return the id of the 'init' process (1)."